# VBA - stop overwriting existing file in SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to prevent saved files from being overwritten and instead saved as ver 1, ver 2 etc. Hope you can help. Sorry I'm very new to this. thanks

So far I have this:

```
Dim formattedDate As String

formattedDate = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:xlTypePDF, FileName"= _

"http://SharePoint.com/program/xxx/xxx/ABC/def/" & _

"ABC - " & _

formattedDate & _

".pdf" _

, Quality:xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _

:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors, e.g. the arguments to `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` should be specified as `Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="", Quality:=xlQualityStandard`, etc. Other than those syntax errors, are you getting an error? Is this doing what you expect?

Comment: You could just add *time* into the `formattedDate` to reduce the re-use of the filename. Alternatively, you need to check if the file (and potentially subsequent versions) exist and add your version number to the filename

Comment: Example  -   `Dim sFilename As String
 sFilename = "U:\Data\err" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddHHMMSS") & ".txt"`

Comment: Welcome Elly! Take the tour and earn a badge  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, yes I'll just add time to it for an easy fix. Thanks again 